# getting Error: How to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible while running my project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, build-error

I am trying to run my old android project in android studio i have updated my gradle version however I am getting the following error:

**Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @13d72a22**

Gradle version: 7.2 JDK version: 17

I have tried gradle property value:

org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xmx2048M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xmx2048M" --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: Can you please include the full stack trace as well as the code causing the issue (or the build.gradle if it doesn't origin from.your code)?

Comment: Why do you need to read a private field that's available through a public method? Just call `file.getPath()`. Or is this in some framework code?

Comment: It's not about file It's jdk error @RobSpoor

Comment: @miral something is trying to use reflection to access a private field from `java.io.File`. The JDK itself should be allowed to do that. Can you add the information that dan1st is on strike asked for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I just download JDK 11 and it's compatibale with AGP 7.2 and it's working

check Compatibility for AGL

https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-7-2-0-release-notes

Comment: I used gradle version "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4' " in the Project build.gradle file (before it was 4.1.0) and JavaVersion.VERSION_17 as compileOptions in the module build.gradle file, and the exception was gone.

Answer (score 18):

**Solution:**
Add the below line in your gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: already tried but now working

Comment: This should be the correct and approved answer.

Comment: it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

[https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#:~:text=A%20Java%20version%20between%208,be%20supported%20in%20Gradle%209.0.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9GP7.png)

[image]

Check Java Compatibility with Gradle & then modify it in Project structure